# How to distribute n identical balls into k identical boxes having different capacities

Tags: statistics, permutation, combinatorics

Suppose there are 4 boxes having capacities 10, 5, 2, 1.Please help me in finding  number of ways to distribute 16 identical balls into these four boxes. Each box can have 0 to the capacity number of the balls.

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify the question to 
"Find number of ways to distribute 2 identical balls into 4 boxes, having capacities 2,2,2 and 1.",
because we can count empty spaces in the original.

1) If we put a ball in 4th box, then we have 3 box for another one - 3 combination.

2) Now we don't put a ball in 4th box at all, so we have 3 box with 2 places.

n^k=2^3=8

In total, we have 8+1=9 combinations.

Answer (score -1):

Let the parts be a_1,...,a_k and sum of them n, there are a total of n! combinations and then so each of the a_i parts are equal so we divide it by all a_i! and then divide it by k!, so the final answer will be:

n!/(a_1! * a_2! * ... * a_k! * k!).

this can be calculate in O(k) with O(n) preprocess using the Fermats theorem.